Can an HTTP Request work with RSYNC?
So I know RSYNC daemon which negates the usage of SSH in order to send or receive files. However, I'm seeing there's some HTTP GET traffic along with a web-scanning user agent over port 873 to these servers which are public, as part of the Client Initialization in Wireshark. Is it possible for the GET request to be processed, or would it be discarded, given that it is not a web server?

Client side would have to send a POST with a form using <input type="file" ... from a browser.  Or with curl: curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F "data=@/path/to/file.ext
